# C++ EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

What's wrong with the class written down, It returns the following error:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

when the operator= is called.

```
class test
{
    int x;
public:
    test()
    {
        this->x=10;
    }

    test(const test& other)
    {
        this->x=other.x;
    }

    test& operator=(const test& other)
    {
        this->x=other.x;
    }

};
```

Comment: Does it work with other operators?

Comment: You are not `return`ing from `operator=`. That's UB.

Comment: @cigien how I missed that!! Thank you a lot

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning from your `operator=`. That invokes undefined behavior.

```
test& operator=(const test& other)
{
   this->x=other.x;
}
```

You need to do:

```
test& operator=(const test& other)
{
   this->x=other.x;
   return *this;
}
```